# Google Cast - Cannot Resolve mSelectedDevice

Tags: java, android, google-cast

I am having a problem making a Google Cast Service. I can not seem to find what to use for mSelectedDevice. Both tutorials that I am using do not provide enough explanation for this, and neither go into detail of what mSelectedDevice should be.

```
public class CastMediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback{

@Override
public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
    mSelectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle(info.getExtras());
    String routeId = info.getId();
    //Startd NanoHTTPD, Find URI of photo/video, and display on Cast device
}

@Override
public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
    teardown();
    mSelectedDevice = null;
}
```

}

(Tutorials I am using: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender /// https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/building-an-android-google-cast-sender-app/161)

Comment: Looks like your example code assumes that it is a `CastDevice` field. `CastDevice.getFromBundle` returns an instance of a `CastDevice`.

Comment: Okay, so what would I need to switch it to? I haven't seen other code use the castdevice field. Even the sample from Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mSelecteDevice` is an instance variable that is of type `CastDevice`. Not sure what you mean by "Google Cast Service" in your question but it seems you might be better off grabbing a sample project from oue [GitHub](https://github.com/googlecast) repo as your starting point.